# Understand Mongoid Query Plan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have little experience with Mongoid and Rails. I am trying to make a query I am writing in my Rails app as performant as possible.

The app has a `User` model and a `WithdrawalHold` model. A user can have many withdrawal_holds.

WithdrawalHold has `user_id` and `hold_until` fields. WithdrawalHold has following indexes:
`index({ user_id: 1, hold_until: 1, _id: -1 }, background: true)`
`index({ hold_until: 1 }, background: true)`

When I run following in Rails console:
`WithdrawalHold.where(:user_id => 1, :hold_until.gte => Time.now).order_by(:hold_until => 'asc').explain`

```
{"queryPlanner"=>
  {"plannerVersion"=>1,
   "namespace"=>"test.limits_withdrawal_holds",
   "indexFilterSet"=>false,
   "parsedQuery"=>{"$and"=>[{"user_id"=>{"$eq"=>1}}, {"hold_until"=>{"$gte"=>2018-02-25 21:53:24 UTC}}]},
   "winningPlan"=>
    {"stage"=>"FETCH",
     "inputStage"=>
      {"stage"=>"IXSCAN",
       "keyPattern"=>{"user_id"=>1, "hold_until"=>1, "_id"=>-1},
       "indexName"=>"user_id_1_hold_until_1__id_-1",
       "isMultiKey"=>false,
       "multiKeyPaths"=>{"user_id"=>[], "hold_until"=>[], "_id"=>[]},
       "isUnique"=>false,
       "isSparse"=>false,
       "isPartial"=>false,
       "indexVersion"=>2,
       "direction"=>"forward",
       "indexBounds"=>{"user_id"=>["[1, 1]"], "hold_until"=>["[new Date(1519595604368), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"], "_id"=>["[MaxKey, MinKey]"]}}},
   "rejectedPlans"=>
    [{"stage"=>"FETCH",
      "filter"=>{"user_id"=>{"$eq"=>1}},
      "inputStage"=>
       {"stage"=>"IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern"=>{"hold_until"=>1},
        "indexName"=>"hold_until_1",
        "isMultiKey"=>false,
        "multiKeyPaths"=>{"hold_until"=>[]},
        "isUnique"=>false,
        "isSparse"=>false,
        "isPartial"=>false,
        "indexVersion"=>2,
        "direction"=>"forward",
        "indexBounds"=>{"hold_until"=>["[new Date(1519595604368), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"]}}}]},
 "executionStats"=>
  {"executionSuccess"=>true,
   "nReturned"=>0,
   "executionTimeMillis"=>0,
   "totalKeysExamined"=>0,
   "totalDocsExamined"=>0,
   "executionStages"=>
    {"stage"=>"FETCH",
     "nReturned"=>0,
     "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
     "works"=>2,
     "advanced"=>0,
     "needTime"=>0,
     "needYield"=>0,
     "saveState"=>0,
     "restoreState"=>0,
     "isEOF"=>1,
     "invalidates"=>0,
     "docsExamined"=>0,
     "alreadyHasObj"=>0,
     "inputStage"=>
      {"stage"=>"IXSCAN",
       "nReturned"=>0,
       "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
       "works"=>1,
       "advanced"=>0,
       "needTime"=>0,
       "needYield"=>0,
       "saveState"=>0,
       "restoreState"=>0,
       "isEOF"=>1,
       "invalidates"=>0,
       "keyPattern"=>{"user_id"=>1, "hold_until"=>1, "_id"=>-1},
       "indexName"=>"user_id_1_hold_until_1__id_-1",
       "isMultiKey"=>false,
       "multiKeyPaths"=>{"user_id"=>[], "hold_until"=>[], "_id"=>[]},
       "isUnique"=>false,
       "isSparse"=>false,
       "isPartial"=>false,
       "indexVersion"=>2,
       "direction"=>"forward",
       "indexBounds"=>{"user_id"=>["[1, 1]"], "hold_until"=>["[new Date(1519595604368), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"], "_id"=>["[MaxKey, MinKey]"]},
       "keysExamined"=>0,
       "seeks"=>1,
       "dupsTested"=>0,
       "dupsDropped"=>0,
       "seenInvalidated"=>0}},
   "allPlansExecution"=>
    [{"nReturned"=>0,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
      "totalKeysExamined"=>1,
      "totalDocsExamined"=>1,
      "executionStages"=>
       {"stage"=>"FETCH",
        "filter"=>{"user_id"=>{"$eq"=>1}},
        "nReturned"=>0,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
        "works"=>1,
        "advanced"=>0,
        "needTime"=>1,
        "needYield"=>0,
        "saveState"=>0,
        "restoreState"=>0,
        "isEOF"=>0,
        "invalidates"=>0,
        "docsExamined"=>1,
        "alreadyHasObj"=>0,
        "inputStage"=>
         {"stage"=>"IXSCAN",
          "nReturned"=>1,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
          "works"=>1,
          "advanced"=>1,
          "needTime"=>0,
          "needYield"=>0,
          "saveState"=>0,
          "restoreState"=>0,
          "isEOF"=>0,
          "invalidates"=>0,
          "keyPattern"=>{"hold_until"=>1},
          "indexName"=>"hold_until_1",
          "isMultiKey"=>false,
          "multiKeyPaths"=>{"hold_until"=>[]},
          "isUnique"=>false,
          "isSparse"=>false,
          "isPartial"=>false,
          "indexVersion"=>2,
          "direction"=>"forward",
          "indexBounds"=>{"hold_until"=>["[new Date(1519595604368), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"]},
          "keysExamined"=>1,
          "seeks"=>1,
          "dupsTested"=>0,
          "dupsDropped"=>0,
          "seenInvalidated"=>0}}},
     {"nReturned"=>0,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
      "totalKeysExamined"=>0,
      "totalDocsExamined"=>0,
      "executionStages"=>
       {"stage"=>"FETCH",
        "nReturned"=>0,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
        "works"=>1,
        "advanced"=>0,
        "needTime"=>0,
        "needYield"=>0,
        "saveState"=>0,
        "restoreState"=>0,
        "isEOF"=>1,
        "invalidates"=>0,
        "docsExamined"=>0,
        "alreadyHasObj"=>0,
        "inputStage"=>
         {"stage"=>"IXSCAN",
          "nReturned"=>0,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
          "works"=>1,
          "advanced"=>0,
          "needTime"=>0,
          "needYield"=>0,
          "saveState"=>0,
          "restoreState"=>0,
          "isEOF"=>1,
          "invalidates"=>0,
          "keyPattern"=>{"user_id"=>1, "hold_until"=>1, "_id"=>-1},
          "indexName"=>"user_id_1_hold_until_1__id_-1",
          "isMultiKey"=>false,
          "multiKeyPaths"=>{"user_id"=>[], "hold_until"=>[], "_id"=>[]},
          "isUnique"=>false,
          "isSparse"=>false,
          "isPartial"=>false,
          "indexVersion"=>2,
          "direction"=>"forward",
          "indexBounds"=>{"user_id"=>["[1, 1]"], "hold_until"=>["[new Date(1519595604368), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"], "_id"=>["[MaxKey, MinKey]"]},
          "keysExamined"=>0,
          "seeks"=>1,
          "dupsTested"=>0,
          "dupsDropped"=>0,
          "seenInvalidated"=>0}}}]},
 "serverInfo"=>{"host"=>"1cf25211760e", "port"=>27017, "version"=>"3.4.9", "gitVersion"=>"876ebee8c7dd0e2d992f36a848ff4dc50ee6603e"},
 "ok"=>1.0}
```

The result indicates that `{ user_id: 1, hold_until: 1, _id: -1 }` index gets used. And number of documents examined is 0 which I believe indicates that the query was covered by an index (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/).

Note, in above query user_id was 1 and there is no user with that ID.

Now, if I use a real user_id (whose type is a BSON::ObjectId):

`WithdrawalHold.where(:user_id => user.id, :hold_until.gte => Time.now).order_by(:hold_until => 'asc').explain`

```
{"queryPlanner"=>
   {"plannerVersion"=>1,
    "namespace"=>"test.limits_withdrawal_holds",
    "indexFilterSet"=>false,
    "parsedQuery"=>{"$and"=>[{"user_id"=>{"$eq"=>BSON::ObjectId('5a932ba8476e0a3ee86a3b5e')}}, {"hold_until"=>{"$gte"=>2018-02-25 21:55:05 UTC}}]},
    "winningPlan"=>
     {"stage"=>"FETCH",
      "filter"=>{"user_id"=>{"$eq"=>BSON::ObjectId('5a932ba8476e0a3ee86a3b5e')}},
      "inputStage"=>
       {"stage"=>"IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern"=>{"hold_until"=>1},
        "indexName"=>"hold_until_1",
        "isMultiKey"=>false,
        "multiKeyPaths"=>{"hold_until"=>[]},
        "isUnique"=>false,
        "isSparse"=>false,
        "isPartial"=>false,
        "indexVersion"=>2,
        "direction"=>"forward",
        "indexBounds"=>{"hold_until"=>["[new Date(1519595705482), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"]}}},
    "rejectedPlans"=>
     [{"stage"=>"FETCH",
       "inputStage"=>
        {"stage"=>"IXSCAN",
         "keyPattern"=>{"user_id"=>1, "hold_until"=>1, "_id"=>-1},
         "indexName"=>"user_id_1_hold_until_1__id_-1",
         "isMultiKey"=>false,
         "multiKeyPaths"=>{"user_id"=>[], "hold_until"=>[], "_id"=>[]},
         "isUnique"=>false,
         "isSparse"=>false,
         "isPartial"=>false,
         "indexVersion"=>2,
         "direction"=>"forward",
         "indexBounds"=>
          {"user_id"=>["[ObjectId('5a932ba8476e0a3ee86a3b5e'), ObjectId('5a932ba8476e0a3ee86a3b5e')]"],
           "hold_until"=>["[new Date(1519595705482), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"],
           "_id"=>["[MaxKey, MinKey]"]}}}]},
  "executionStats"=>
   {"executionSuccess"=>true,
    "nReturned"=>3,
    "executionTimeMillis"=>0,
    "totalKeysExamined"=>3,
    "totalDocsExamined"=>3,
    "executionStages"=>
     {"stage"=>"FETCH",
      "filter"=>{"user_id"=>{"$eq"=>BSON::ObjectId('5a932ba8476e0a3ee86a3b5e')}},
      "nReturned"=>3,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
      "works"=>5,
      "advanced"=>3,
      "needTime"=>0,
      "needYield"=>0,
      "saveState"=>0,
      "restoreState"=>0,
      "isEOF"=>1,
      "invalidates"=>0,
      "docsExamined"=>3,
      "alreadyHasObj"=>0,
      "inputStage"=>
       {"stage"=>"IXSCAN",
        "nReturned"=>3,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
        "works"=>4,
        "advanced"=>3,
        "needTime"=>0,
        "needYield"=>0,
        "saveState"=>0,
        "restoreState"=>0,
        "isEOF"=>1,
        "invalidates"=>0,
        "keyPattern"=>{"hold_until"=>1},
        "indexName"=>"hold_until_1",
        "isMultiKey"=>false,
        "multiKeyPaths"=>{"hold_until"=>[]},
        "isUnique"=>false,
        "isSparse"=>false,
        "isPartial"=>false,
        "indexVersion"=>2,
        "direction"=>"forward",
        "indexBounds"=>{"hold_until"=>["[new Date(1519595705482), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"]},
        "keysExamined"=>3,
        "seeks"=>1,
        "dupsTested"=>0,
        "dupsDropped"=>0,
        "seenInvalidated"=>0}},
    "allPlansExecution"=>
     [{"nReturned"=>3,
       "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
       "totalKeysExamined"=>3,
       "totalDocsExamined"=>3,
       "executionStages"=>
        {"stage"=>"FETCH",
         "nReturned"=>3,
         "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
         "works"=>4,
         "advanced"=>3,
         "needTime"=>0,
         "needYield"=>0,
         "saveState"=>0,
         "restoreState"=>0,
         "isEOF"=>1,
         "invalidates"=>0,
         "docsExamined"=>3,
         "alreadyHasObj"=>0,
         "inputStage"=>
          {"stage"=>"IXSCAN",
           "nReturned"=>3,
           "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
           "works"=>4,
           "advanced"=>3,
           "needTime"=>0,
           "needYield"=>0,
           "saveState"=>0,
           "restoreState"=>0,
           "isEOF"=>1,
           "invalidates"=>0,
           "keyPattern"=>{"user_id"=>1, "hold_until"=>1, "_id"=>-1},
           "indexName"=>"user_id_1_hold_until_1__id_-1",
           "isMultiKey"=>false,
           "multiKeyPaths"=>{"user_id"=>[], "hold_until"=>[], "_id"=>[]},
           "isUnique"=>false,
           "isSparse"=>false,
           "isPartial"=>false,
           "indexVersion"=>2,
           "direction"=>"forward",
           "indexBounds"=>
            {"user_id"=>["[ObjectId('5a932ba8476e0a3ee86a3b5e'), ObjectId('5a932ba8476e0a3ee86a3b5e')]"],
             "hold_until"=>["[new Date(1519595705482), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"],
             "_id"=>["[MaxKey, MinKey]"]},
           "keysExamined"=>3,
           "seeks"=>1,
           "dupsTested"=>0,
           "dupsDropped"=>0,
           "seenInvalidated"=>0}}},
      {"nReturned"=>3,
       "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
       "totalKeysExamined"=>3,
       "totalDocsExamined"=>3,
       "executionStages"=>
        {"stage"=>"FETCH",
         "filter"=>{"user_id"=>{"$eq"=>BSON::ObjectId('5a932ba8476e0a3ee86a3b5e')}},
         "nReturned"=>3,
         "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
         "works"=>4,
         "advanced"=>3,
         "needTime"=>0,
         "needYield"=>0,
         "saveState"=>0,
         "restoreState"=>0,
         "isEOF"=>1,
         "invalidates"=>0,
         "docsExamined"=>3,
         "alreadyHasObj"=>0,
         "inputStage"=>
          {"stage"=>"IXSCAN",
           "nReturned"=>3,
           "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
           "works"=>4,
           "advanced"=>3,
           "needTime"=>0,
           "needYield"=>0,
           "saveState"=>0,
           "restoreState"=>0,
           "isEOF"=>1,
           "invalidates"=>0,
           "keyPattern"=>{"hold_until"=>1},
           "indexName"=>"hold_until_1",
           "isMultiKey"=>false,
           "multiKeyPaths"=>{"hold_until"=>[]},
           "isUnique"=>false,
           "isSparse"=>false,
           "isPartial"=>false,
           "indexVersion"=>2,
           "direction"=>"forward",
           "indexBounds"=>{"hold_until"=>["[new Date(1519595705482), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"]},
           "keysExamined"=>3,
           "seeks"=>1,
           "dupsTested"=>0,
           "dupsDropped"=>0,
           "seenInvalidated"=>0}}}]},
  "serverInfo"=>{"host"=>"1cf25211760e", "port"=>27017, "version"=>"3.4.9", "gitVersion"=>"876ebee8c7dd0e2d992f36a848ff4dc50ee6603e"},
  "ok"=>1.0}
```

The result indicates that only the `{ hold_until: 1 }` index gets used and that a number of documents get examined.

I'd like to understand why the difference in the plan for the two queries and if it is possible to write this query such that it is completely covered by indexes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It has been almost two years since you asked.
Nobody answers the question so far, since, I guess, the answer will attract potential downvotes.
I wonder if any answer would still be relevant to you.

I neither know what you have in the collection nor deeply know lots about MongoDB indexing, but the winning plan is to "FETCH" is a good sign. It means that your index is working.
In contrast, if no index has been used at all, the plan would be "COLLSCAN".

Now breaking the rest of the issues:

- Why did some numbers of documents get examined?

  - At least, MongoDB needs to examine what they returned. The same value of "nReturned" and "docsExamined" is an indication that MongoDB did not touch other documents besides the ones returned.
- Why did it not pick another plan but instead reject it?

  - I cannot pinpoint the exact reason here, but the database determined that using the index it chooses is statistically more efficient.
    It may depend on the data stored on the collection, for example in an SQL implementation, even if the table contains BTREE indexes, sometimes the planner refuses to use BTREE and scan the table instead because the table contains one or only a few rows of data. The BTREE lookup just does not worth it.
    A similar thing can happen for MongoDB too.
    And the only one who can tell you exactly why is the person who optimizes the database for this case.

The main take-home here is: sometimes you need to let it go. If you want every single detail to be exact, you will accomplish not as much as people with a healthy level of ignorance. And if the database runs well enough, it means that you are doing good enough.